# how to generate sequence of values in SQLite when lower and upper bounds are taken from another table?

Tags: sqlite, generate-series

I can use SQLite's built-in `generate_sequence` function to create a series of values with a known (constant) lower and upper bound:

```
sqlite> select value from generate_series(1, 5);
1
2
3
4
5
```

How do I generate such a sequence if the lower and upper bounds must be based on values from some table? For example, suppose I have:

```
sqlite> create table temp(
......>     num integer not null
......> );
sqlite> insert into temp values (1), (5);
sqlite> select * from temp;
1
5
```

The following (quite reasonably) gives a parse error:

```
sqlite> select value from generate_series(
......>     select min(num) from temp,
......>     select max(num) from temp
......> );
```

Is it possible to do what I want without using a recursive CTE? (My actual use case requires a series of dates based on the minimum and maximum dates in a dataset, but if I can get a series of integers, generating dates will be straightforward.)

Answer (score 3):

```
select value from generate_series(
    (select min(num) from temp), 
    (select max(num) from temp)
);
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: I'll be damned - works if the parameter expressions inside generate_series() are parenthesized, but doesn't work if they aren't. thank you

Comment: @GregWilson: You may want to consider marking this as the accepted answer if it resolves your issue.